# Blender 2.8 Sculpting splitting at edges

Tags: vertices, edges, sculpting

I'm a noob I've looked all over and I don't know what to search for, so I've not had much luck, I apologize in advance. I'm using blender 2.8.

So I have an object that I want to sculpt on. Its been imported from a game.

It pulls apart from the seams even after dyntopo and I think it needs vertices added on edges that touch, that don't have vertices on them in that location, if that makes any sense.

Example 2 is just showing that there is no vertice on that edge. Is there a way to auto add vertices on edges that touch an edge that has vertices, that way I can remove doubles and have everything connected? Or am I going about this all wrong?

There are a lot of them that's why I want an easy way.

I just want everything to be connected together so I can sculpt on it and not have it splitting at the edges.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid thanks and other unnecessary words.  It consumer time of the readers which can be used to help you. : )

Comment: Unfortunately there is no automatic way to fix bad topology - neither in Blender nor in any other 3D modelling software. Without knowing anything about your model, the only method that comes to mind is retopologizing the model into a new one.

Comment: @metaphor_set, there are tricks that you can use to fix problems though.  For example loop cut and slide to create an edge from `2` to `<-` would work depending on topology.

Answer (score 1):

Also a noob here. A solution I found is to go to edit mode, select all the vertices around the edge of the hole, click on the button that says 'Face' in the top left, then select the fill option. Only just found it and haven't tested it too much.

Comment: You can also hit the `F` key, which means 'fill'

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the parts in the game model aren't connected to start with (common for game models).

Looking at what you have, I might try recreating the geometry using the "remesh" modifier, but this will destory materials, UV (texture) maps, etc. You are right in thinking that one edge cannot also be two edges on an adjacent face, and you can subdivide the longer edge then move vertices around till they are in the same place and edge is matched to edge, but you must then select all and "merge by distance" to connect the two. This would also mess up UV maps if you care about them.

More information:

If the creators simply used split edges to create sharp edges (edges of the faces are always next to the edge of another face so it looks connected), you can try selecting all then "merge by distance."

However, if one geometry is intersecting another, such as a fin stuck into the surface of something, or one edge is next to two, that will not work.

The method described in a previous answer of creating faces will work to create manifold (physically possible with no holes) geometry, but could end up making faces with zero area (can be removed automatically with "degenerate dissolve"), and would not work for the fin-stuck-in-surface scenario. Also, the handmade face making would be tedious.